# Error on a function: non-static member function

Tags: c++, function, opencv, member, non-static

I am trying to do two functions in parallel, with C++ and OpenCV. The two functions are almost equal. I report only one of them.
I use `std::async` but I receive this error:

```
error: reference to non-static member function must be called
auto Match = async(launch::async, **_find_mouth**, ref(image), ref(mouth));
```

here is the code:

```
using namespace std;
double _find_mouth(Mat img, Rect_<int> & finalMouth) //this is my function
{
//some operations on image
return bestMatch;
}
...
int main(){
auto Match = async(launch::async, _find_mouth, ref(image), ref(mouth)); //here is where I call it
}
```

Where is the problem? What's wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe _find_mouth is static. You need to declare it in some class and pass an instance of that function:  &a._find_mouth (a being the instance of the class that contains _find_mouth)

Comment: What compiler are you using? Your sample compiles fine with GCC 4.8.2 and clang 3.7.0

Comment: If `_find_mouth()` is a non-static member function then you need an instance off of which to call it. That is passed as the argument following the member function.